# problems with a batch api module

Tags: 7, batch-operations

The function `_calcular_tiempo_usuario` isn't called, and is not saving anything in the `$_SESSION` variable.

```
<?php
function proyecto_estadisticas_menu(){
  $items['admin/settings/proyecto_estadisticas/batchapi'] = array(
    'title' => t('Proceso batchapi para calcular tiempo medio en la página'),
    'page callback' => '_proyecto_estadisticas_tiempo',

    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file'  => 'proyecto_estadisticas.batch.inc',
    'type'  => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,  
  );
  return $items;
  }


//archivo de php para los procesos de batch.api
/**
 * Esta función es la que empieza montando todo el proceso de batch api.
 * 
 * name proyecto_comienzo_batch
 * 
 */
function proyecto(){

  //llamamos a la función de batch
  batch_set(_cargar_usuarios());

  batch_process('node');

  /
}

function _cargar_usuarios(){
  //$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday'));
  $date = '2011-09-12';
  $valoresfechas = _get_valores_fechas($date);
  $usuarios = array();
  //se ejecuta correctamente. se ha comprobado.
  $usuarios = _crear_array_usuarios_tiempos( $valoresfechas);

  $operations = array();
  foreach($usuarios as $key => $value){
    $operations[] = array('_calcular_tiempo_usuario', array($key, $value, $valoresfechas));
  }

  $batch = array(
    'operations' => $operations,
    'finished' => 'funcion_final',
    'title' => t('Calculando tiempo de usuarios'),
    'init_message' => t('Comienza el cálculo de tiempos.'),
  );
  return $batch; 
} 

/**
 *
 * Esta función es parte de la batch api que llama a todos los usuarios para recorrer el resultado y hacer el sumatorio.
 * _calcular_tiempo_usuario
 * 151 (Array, 8 elements)
 *   0 (String, 17 characters ) opened 1315836623
 *   1 (String, 17 characters ) closed 1315836924
 * 
 * name _calcular_tiempo_usuario
 * @param $usuario es un array con todos los resultados de opened y closed del usuario que se pasas
 * @return el resultado de la suma.
 * 
 */ 

function _calcular_tiempo_usuario($uid, $usuario, $valoresfechas, &$context){
  $_SESSION['metricas'][$uid] = $uid;
  //contamos la cantidad de elementos del array para los for.
  $cantidad = count($usuario);

  //Comprobamos cual es el primer elemento, opened or closed
  if(preg_match("/^opened/", $usuario[0])){
    $si = 0;
  }else {
    $si = 1; 
  }
  //si $si == 1, quiere decir que el array empiza con un cloused, y el segundo valor(1) es un opened.
  if($si == 1){
    //calculamos el primer valor que es un cloused
    $suma +=  str_replace('closed','',$usuario[0])- $valoresfechas['antes'] ;
    //recorremos el bucle para sacar todas las relaciones
    for($si; $si <= $cantidad; $si=$si+2){
      if($usuario[$si+1]){
        $suma += str_replace('closed','',$usuario[$si+1])-str_replace('opened','',$usuario[$si]);
      }
      if( !($usuario[$si+1]) && (preg_match("/^opened/", $usuario[$si])) ){
        //el ultimo registro, si es open, quiere decir que la sesión ha permanecido abierta all llegar a la media noche, por lo 
        //tanto el close es fecha hasta.
        $suma += $valoresfechas['despues'] -str_replace('opened','',$usuario[$si]);
      }
    }
  }
  //si $si== 0 es que la primera entrada es opened
  if($si == 0){
    //recorremos el bucle para sacar todas las relaciones
    for($si; $si <= $cantidad; $si=$si+2){
      if($usuario[$si+1]){
        $suma += str_replace('closed','',$usuario[$si+1])-str_replace('opened','',$usuario[$si]);
      }
      if( !($usuario[$si+1]) && (preg_match("/^opened/", $usuario[$si])) ){
        //el ultimo registro, si es open, quiere decir que la sesión ha permanecido abierta all llegar a la media noche, por lo 
        //tanto el close es fecha hasta.
        $suma += $valoresfechas['despues'] -str_replace('opened','',$usuario[$si]);
      }
    }
  }
    // Store some result for post-processing in the finished callback.
  $context['results'][] = $uid ;

  // Optional message displayed under the progressbar.
  $context['message'] = t('Loading @uid', array('@uid' => $uid));

  $context['results']['metricas'][$uid]= $suma;
}

/**
 * Batch 'finished' callback 
 */
function funcion_final($success, $results, $operations) {
  if ($success) {
    // Here we could do something meaningful with the results.
    // We just display the number of nodes we processed...
    $message = count($results) . ' processed.';
  }
  else {
    // An error occurred.
    // $operations contains the operations that remained unprocessed.
    $error_operation = reset($operations);
    $message = 'An error occurred while processing ' . $error_operation[0] . ' with arguments :' . print_r($error_operation[0], TRUE);
  }
  drupal_set_message($message);

}

/**
 * Esta función crea un gran array con todos los usuarios y sus registros 
 * de aperturas y cierres de sesión.
 * 
 * name: _crear_array_usuarios_tiempos
 * @param $valoresfechas
 * @return un array con todos los usuarios, menos administradores, y 
 * sus aperturas y cierras de sesión
 * 
 */ 

function _crear_array_usuarios_tiempos( $valoresfechas){

    $sql = db_query("
  SELECT DISTINCT(wid), type, message, uid, timestamp
        FROM watchdog
        WHERE type = 'user'
        AND timestamp > %d
        AND timestamp < %d     
        AND ( message like '%%Session opened for%%' OR message like '%%Session closed for%%')
        AND uid NOT IN (".db_placeholders(ADMINISTRADORES,'int').")
        ORDER BY timestamp ASC",
        $valoresfechas['antes'],
        $valoresfechas['despues'], ADMINISTRADORES  
        );
    while ($result = db_fetch_object($sql)){
      $usuarios[$result->uid][] = limpiar_mensaje($result->message). $result->timestamp;

    }

  return $usuarios;
}
?>
```

Comment: Oskar, could you please explain more what you expect this code to achieve?

Comment: Are there any warnings , notifications or errors ?

Answer (score 0):

The reasong of why the `_calcular_tiempo_usuario()` is not being called or why the  `$_SESSION` variable is not being saved is following:

On the hook_menu(), the callback function is
   `_proyecto_estadisticas_tiempo`, but is the `proyecto()` function which starts the batch process.

Sometimes when you work with batch API you don't see any errors, to confirm that, always check the admin/reports/dblog page.

I couldn't find where do you use the values that should be stored by the $_SESSION  variable, but I suggest you to use:

- `$context['sandbox'][values you need to store]` to store and use those values during batch process.
- `$context['results'][values you need to store]` to use the values after batch process is finished.

You can check it at the [Batch API docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/180528)